# UACの確認ダイアログで画面を暗転させる理由は？

Tags: windows, security

Windows Vista から導入されたUAC（ユーザーアクセス制御）では、特権の必要な操作を実行するときに確認のダイアログが表示されます。この際デフォルトでは画面全体が暗転します。

「デスクトップを暗転しない」という設定もありますが、推奨されませんと注意書きがあります。

セキュリティリスクが高まるのだろうと思いますが、暗転なしでは可能で、暗転ありでは不可能な攻撃というのは、具体的にはどのようなものなのでしょうか。

また、同じような暗転を自分のアプリケーションに実装することもできるのでしょうか。

※単純に画面を暗くするという意味の「暗転」ではなく、UACの設定における「デスクトップを暗転しない」のリスクを知りたいという意図でした。ですからセキュアデスクトップへの切り替えも含みます。

Comment: 私の知る限りでは、純粋に暗転だけをOFFにすることはできなかったと思います。セキュアデスクトップをOFFに設定するとついでに暗転もなくなるだけではないでしょうか。暗転そのものはユーザーへの注意喚起以外の効果はないと思います。

Comment: @h2so5 あ、そうです。設定画面上でも「デスクトップを暗転しない」としか書かれていないので、それに合わせて（セキュアデスクトップへの切り替えを含めて）暗転と書きました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

あの暗転は「セキュリティで保護されたデスクトップ」への切り替えです。

Windowsの仕様では非表示のデスクトップからキーイベントのメッセージをフックすることはできませんので、デスクトップを切り替えることでキーロガーを回避しているのだと思います。

Comment: UACダイアログだけでなく、スクリーンセーバー、ロック画面、ログインダイアログでもこの「セキュリティで保護されたデスクトップ」が使われています。暗転は切り替わっていることを強調する目的です。